# Trackpad does not function after 8 hours of sleep

Tags: sleep-wake, high-sierra

Yesterday I left my MacBook to sleep for a long 8 hours and usually I wake up my MacBook by clicking the trackpad but today surprisingly the trackpad did not have that 'click' noise I could move the cursor around but I could not click on anything but after a restart the trackpad functioned correctly. This problem is occurring the first time for me this never occurred to me I just want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me before to many times. I haven't found one particular thing that works every-time, but after I try different things it eventually starts back up.

**Possible solution #1**

1. Unplug all external device from the computer
2. Hold the power button for 20 seconds then release
3. Click the power button in attempt to boot

This sometimes works for me, if it doesn't work, try Possible Solution #2

**Possible solution #2**

Try an [SMC Reset](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201295)

If this doesn't work then I attempt Possible Solution #2 again. I basically just loop the 2 solutions. Also sometimes leaving it for 5-10 minutes after a couple of cycles.

I apologize that this isn't that exact. But this is my method of fixing this issue, and it has always eventually worked for me.

Comment: I will try out soon and update.